# How to do diagnostic analysis with the systemfit package?

Tags: r, regression, data-analysis, autocorrect, correlated

How to do the diagnostic analysis of the model adjusted by the systemfit package, for example:

```
library(systemfit)
data("Kmenta")

eqDemand  <- consump ~ price + income
eqSupply  <- consump ~ price + farmPrice + trend 
system    <- list( demand = eqDemand, supply = eqSupply )

fitsur    <- systemfit( system, "SUR", data = Kmenta, maxit = 100 )
influence.measures(fitsur)
```

> Error in UseMethod("influence")

[help of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/systemfit.pdf)

Comment: The function `influence.measures` isn't defined for `systemfit` models (it's only meant to work with linear and generalized linear models). What exactly did you need this function to return?

Comment: I would like to have the dffits, dfbetas, cooks distance of the model